# How to display the grid when multiple matplotlib charts are created at the same time?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to use the grid in multiple matplotlib figures, but if I just use `plt.grid()` the grid would only show up in one of the charts.

How can I change the code below, so that the grid shows up in both figures, please?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng(19680801)
N_points = 100000
dist1 = rng.standard_normal(N_points)

fig = plt.figure()
axis = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

fig1 = plt.figure()
ax = fig1.add_subplot(1,1,1)

axis.hist(dist1)

ax.hist(dist1)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng(19680801)
N_points = 100000
dist1 = rng.standard_normal(N_points)

fig = plt.figure()
axis = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
axis.grid()
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax = fig1.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.grid()

axis.hist(dist1)

ax.hist(dist1)
# plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Ah, so I have to call .grid() on the axis. Thank you! :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).